# Store entry index page to cookie and send visitor back to that index page regardless of folder

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a site that will have a slightly different homepage / index page depending on which state a visitor is from. Now, let's say a visitor enters the site via, for example, `https://www.example.com/FLORIDA/index.html`, if they then browse around and click a top level page like `https://www.example.com/about.html` and then click the homepage link somewhere on that page, I'd like them to actually return to the `https://www.example.com/FLORIDA/index.html` homepage that they entered the session/visit from rather than go to the default `index.html`.

Pages like About Us, Terms, Privacy, Contact, etc. will all obviously be top folder pages. So, if someone enters the site via `/FLORIDA/index.html` and then visits `about.html`, if they then click the homepage link at the top of `about.html`, they would go to default `index.html`. So is it possible to store the fact that they entered the site via `https://www.example.com/FLORIDA/index.html` to a cookie and return them to that index page if they browse around and then click a homepage link from elsewhere in the site?

Comment: Do you need to know the state on the server? If not, use localStorage instead of cookies.

Comment: @mplungjan I hadn't heard of localStorage before. Thanks. It seems interesting. Do you perhaps know of a resource that would give me an idea of how I can implement specifically the above kind of scenario with localStorage? I'm very new to Javascript and having looked at some resources regarding localStorage now, I'm not quite sure how the above kind of strings or arguments, etc. would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple version - visit any /state/index.html and the state is remembered in localStorage

You include JS on each page (using external JS file) where you have a home URL - the link needs `id="home"`

The script ASSUMES that you have ALWAYS yourserver.com/state/index.html

If not you need to change the ternary

```
let state = parts.length === 3 ? parts[1] : "";
```

Here is the code to copy

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  const url = new URL(location.href); 
  const parts = url.pathname.split("/"); // creates ["","page.html"] OR ["","state","index.html"]
  let state = parts.length === 3 ? parts[1] : ""; // get the state from the URL OR
  if (state === "") { // get the state from localStorage instead
    state = localStorage.getItem("state") || ""; 
  }
  if (state) { // do we NOW have a state?
    localStorage.setItem("state",state); 
    url.pathname = state ? "/"+state+"/index.html" : "/index.html";
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".home")].forEach(lnk => lnk.href = url);
  }  
})
```

Because the stacksnippets do not support localStorage, you need to uncomment and delete lines when you copy the code to your server.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  // const url = new URL(location.href); // uncomment on your server
  const url = new URL("https://yourserver.com/florida/index.html"); // remove when on your server
  const parts = url.pathname.split("/"); // creates ["","page.html"] OR ["","state","index.html"]
  console.log(parts)
  let state = parts.length === 3 ? parts[1] : ""; // get the state from the URL OR
  if (state === "") { // get the state from localStorage instead
  // state = localStorage.getItem("state") || ""; // uncomment on your server
  }
  if (state) { // do we NOW have a state?
    // localStorage.setItem("state",state); // uncomment on your server
    url.pathname = state ? "/"+state+"/index.html" : "/index.html";
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".home")].forEach(lnk => lnk.href = url);
  }  
})
```

```html
<a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
```

Full example

The code below does the following

- sets the active page based on the URL so you need to match about to about - case sensitive
- sets the state from localStorage if already set before
- sets the state from dropdown. It could reload the page if needed

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when page loads
  // const url = new URL(location.href); // uncomment on your server
  const url = new URL("https://yourserver.com/tutorials"); // remove when on your server
  const ul = document.getElementById("links");
  // let state = localStorage.getItem("state") || ""; // uncomment on your server
  let state = "FLORIDA"; // remove from code on your server

  // state selection
  const stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel");
  if (state) { // already have a state
    stateSel.value=state;
  }
  stateSel.onchange=function() { // using onchange to trigger later
    state = this.value;
    // localStorage.setItem("state",state); // uncomment on your server
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".home")].forEach(lnk => lnk.href = url);
  };
  stateSel.onchange(); // set the link when loading page
  // active link
  [...ul.querySelectorAll("li")].forEach(function(li) {
    const page = li.getAttribute("data-page");
    li.querySelector("a").classList.toggle("active", url.pathname.indexOf(page) != -1); // set active
  })
})
```

```css
/* from https://css-snippets.com/simple-horizontal-navigation/ */

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul id="links">
    <li data-page="/index"><a id="home" href="index">Home</a></li>
    <li data-page="/tutorials"><a href="tutorials">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li data-page="/about"><a href="about">About</a></li>
    <li data-page="/news"><a href="news">Newsletter</a></li>
    <li data-page="/contact"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<select id="stateSel">
  <option value="">Which state?</option>
  <option value="FLORIDA">Florida</option>
  <option value="NEVADA">Nevada</option>
</select>
```

Comment: mplungjan, you are a genius and a legend. I really appreciate your time and effort above here, seriously. But I think this is perhaps overcomplicated for my scenario and is different to my site setup. My scenario is pretty simple. If someone enters the site via https://www.example.com/oregon/index.html, from then on, if they then click any index.html homepage link, they go to https://www.example.com/oregon/index.html. If they enter from https://www.example.com/california/index.html and then later click any index.html link to the homepage, they go to https://www.example.com/oregon/index.html.

Comment: I think you meant California in the last link. I’ll look later

Comment: Ha, yes, you're right. example.com/california/index.html to example.com/california/index.html, example.com/nevada/index.html to example.com/nevada/index.html, etc. Just storing that entry page variable, if you can call it that, to that visitor so that from then on, whenever they click an anchor in the site that links to index.html, they will go to the example.com/StateName/index.html they entered from. And thanks.

Comment: Can I rely on the state to ALWAYS be yoursite.com/STATE/index.html?

Comment: See the updated answer. The first code should set the link with id="home" on any page to either /index.html or /state/index.html depending on you having been to /state/index.html or not

Comment: Hi, mplungjan. Sorry, was away from keyboard. Yes, the state would always be mysite.com/state/index.html. Thank you for the updated code. That looks very good to my untrained eye :) I will test this very soon and get back to you. I am away from the computer with the site on it for a little bit and can't do much on my phone but will test as soon as possible. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to be working though unfortunately. If I visit thesite.com/oregon/index.html and then click, say, contact.html on that page to go to the top-folder contact page and then click the home link on that contact page, it just goes to thesite.com/index.html instead of thesite.com/oregon/index.html.

Comment: I have not tested the code live. Any console messages? Is the script loaded on ache page that has a home link plus the Oregon/index.html page?

Comment: Ps my contact details are in my profile if you want to send me the url

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I'm checking some things with it. I'm not seeing any console issues. I will contact you soon via your .name if that's okay.

Comment: Superb. Works perfectly when set up for classes. Excellent piece of code.

Comment: I added this: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".home")].forEach(lnk => lnk.href = url);` needs another type of loop for IE11 though